# capistrano and assets:precompile not working due to rake versioning issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, capistrano

I get the following error on a capistrano deploy:

[image]

If I run that commmand from the command line, I get the following:
You have already activated rake 0.9.2, but your Gemfile requires rake 10.0.3. Using bundle exec may solve this.

From my Gemfile

```
gem 'rake', '10.0.3'
```

When I look at Gemfile.lock, I see only three mentions of rake:

```
railties (3.1.10)
  rake (>= 0.8.7)
rake (10.0.3)
rake (= 10.0.3)
```

This seems like fixing it at 10.0.3 should be fine.

Why am I getting this and how do I resolve this? What would happen if I ran `gem uninstall rake`? Would Capistrano still work after that?

thx in advance

**edit 1**
different rake versions:

```
root@curren:/data/sites/domain.com/apps/app-rails/current# rake -V
rake, version 0.9.2
root@curren:/data/sites/domain.com/apps/app-rails/current# bundle exec rake -V
rake, version 10.0.3
```

Comment: so why dont u use `bundle exec rake ...` ?

Comment: uh, it's a capistrano task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no reason not to update rake, you can run

```
bundle update rake
```

This will actually update your Gemfile.lock to use the newest version of rake

if you want to keep rake 0.9.2 uninstall the newest

```
gem uninstall rake
#result on my box
Select gem to uninstall:
 1. rake-0.8.7
 2. rake-10.0.1
 3. rake-10.0.2
 4. All versions
```

[This Yehuda Katz blog post explains more](http://yehudakatz.com/2011/05/30/gem-versioning-and-bundler-doing-it-right/).

Answer (score 3):

For Cap 3:

```
SSHKit.config.command_map[:rake] = "bundle exec rake"
```